# HTML template not being rendered as expected by flask

Tags: html, flask

It's my first time creating a web app with flask and I need to do it for a semester project so I only understand the very basics of this framework. Here's the problem that I'm facing currently, the '/cart' URL is only displaying the view cart button instead of displaying the relevant cart information.
Note: I know that using OOP with flask isn't really the best approach out there but we're kinda required to do so, please ignore any redundant blocks of code if there are any.
Here's the code:

```
def cart(self):

    if request.method=='GET':
        self.req = request.form.get('dept')
        self.req1 = request.form.get('Quantity')
        with open('prodinfo.csv') as f:
            csv_read=csv.reader(f)
            for i in csv_read:
                if i[0]==self.req:
                    i[1]=i[1]*int(self.req1)
                    self.cartl.append(i)
                    return render_template('history.html',hist=self.cartl)
        return render_template('products.html')






def cartdisplay(self):
        app=CustProduct()
        return app.cart()
```

here's how I'm calling '/cart':

```
@obj.route('/cart',methods=['GET',"POST"])
def call5():
app=History()

return app.cartdisplay()
```

This is the code from 'history.html':

```
{% block body %}
{% for item in hist %}
    <form action="/cart" method="get">
      <p>{{item[0]}}
          <br>
        {{item[1]}}</p>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

and this is the code from 'products.html':

```
{% for prod in prods %}
    <form action="/login/products" method="post">
        <input type="number" name="Quantity" min=1 max=10 id="Quantity">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name='dept' id='dept' value={{prod[0]}}>
        <br>

    </form>
    <form action="/login/products" method="get">
         <button type="Submit" name='Ret' id='Ret'><img src={{prod[2]}} class="teal">Add to Cart</button>
    </form>
{% endfor %}
<form action="/cart" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="carts" id="carts" value="viewcart">
</form>
```

here's the other function which is rendering the same template for reference:

```
def prodview(self):
        with open('prodinfo.csv', 'r') as prodf:
            prodread = csv.reader(prodf, delimiter=',')
            next(prodread)
            for line in prodread:
                self.prods.append(line)
        return render_template('products.html', prods=self.prods)
```

Comment: In your 'products.html' you are iterating through a variable called `prods`. Where does this come from? It should be passed to the template when it is rendered if you want the relevant cart information to be displayed.

Comment: It's defined in another function of the same class, I'm rendering the same template through that function.

Comment: I see, well in the `cart` function, `prods` will also need to be passed to the template in order for it to loop through this variable. Or maybe I'm misunderstanding you, in that case, it would be helpful to [edit] your question to include this other function.

Comment: That didn't really work but I've edited my question to include the other function as well.

Comment: I'm thinking that the `'/cart'` route calls the `cartdisplay` function, which in turn calls the `cart` function. This last function renders the template without passing `prods` to it. Therefore, it will work when you render the template through `prodview`, but not `cart`.